# Gridview loses it's data when command buttons (Edit, Update, Cancel) are clicked

Tags: asp.net

everyone.  I'm writing a fairly simple page, with a GridView that gets data from an SQLDataSource, which I've done before.  When the page loads, it does an initial search which displays information suited to the person accessing the page.  That works fine.  I can vary the search terms and issue the modified query, and that works.  However, when I click on the Edit button, the Gridview vanishes and the EmptyDataText appears.  If i hit the button to re-submit the search, the Gridview re-appears in edit mode.  I can modify fields and hit the Update button, and get EmptyDataText again. Re-submitting the search, the Gridview reappears, with the changed fields updated to the new values.

I can catch the OnRowEditing event, which shows that the button works.  I can catch the RowDatabound event that immediately follows - the Gridview is still visible, and I assume that it's processing the header row.  On hitting Continue, I get EmptyDataText and do not see a RowDataBound event again.  My hypothesis is that it goes looking for the data in the first data row, and doesn't find any, hence the text display.

When I re-submit the search, I again see RowDataBound events, and on the event corresponding to the row with the clicked Edit button, I watch the pre-processing of the Edit mode display - this includes copying an ItemList from a search-criteria DropDownList to an EditTemplate DropDownList. On the n + !st Step Into, the GridView displays, with the correct row in Edit mode.

A similar pattern holds when I hit either Update or Cancel.  It looks like the GridView is losing it's link to data when any of the Command buttons are hit, and requires a re-submission of the search to re-establish the link.  I have tried to re-bind the grid at all points that I can think of (either re-setting the DataSourceID string, or that and issuing a DataBind() call) at PageLoad, and at various event handlers.  However, I've done this sort of linking and editing in the past without having to be quite so draconian.  It seems obvious that I'm missing some critical, and probably rather minor, step that makes this situation different.  Right now, I just want to figure out how to have the Gridview enter Edit mode and re-render without losing it's link to datarows when it enters Edit mode following the completion of OnRowEditing.  Any thoughts?

Here's the Gridview in question:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTaskStatus" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No tasks match your search criteria"  
 AllowSorting="true"  Visible="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
 DataKeyNames="EDA_RequestID"
 CssClass="GenDisplayStyle"  CellPadding="3"
 AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Size="X-Small"  

 OnSorted="gvSorted"                    
 OnRowUpdating="gvTask_OnRowUpdating" 
 OnRowUpdated="gvTask_OnRowUpdated" 
 OnRowCancelingEdit="gvTask_OnRowCancelled"  
 OnRowDataBound="gvTaskStatus_RowDataBound" 
 OnRowEditing="gvTaskStatus_OnRowEditing"
 >

<HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" />
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="AliceBlue"/>

<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="EDA_RequestID" HeaderText="Request ID" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="Requestor" HeaderText="Requestor"  
              SortExpression="Requestor" ReadOnly="true"/>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="Project Name" 
              SortExpression="ProjectName" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField="ChargeNumber" HeaderText="Charge Number"
              SortExpression="ChargeNumber" />

  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assigned To" SortExpression="AssignedTo" >
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("AssignedTo")%>' runat="server" ID="ShowAssigned" />
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="EditAssigned" AutoPostBack="False"    
                           OnSelectedIndexChanged="PersonAssigned" >
         </asp:DropDownList>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="MEPartNumber" HeaderText="Part Number"  
                SortExpression="MEPartNumber" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ReceivedDate" HeaderText="Date Submitted"  
             SortExpression="ReceivedDate" ReadOnly="true"/>
    <!-- Some rows, all boundfields, deleted for length  -->        

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the data source:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="EDASource" runat="server" 
        DataSourceMode="DataSet" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"    
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MECDConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" OnSelected="SqlDataSelectedEvent" >

     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="MEPNTxt"    ControlID="MEPNTxt"      PropertyName="Text"   Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="CommentsTxt" ControlID="CommentsTxt" PropertyName="Text"   Type="String" />  
        <asp:Parameter Name="AssignedTo" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="TopStatus"  Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Requestor"  Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SubmitDate" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>

     <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdEDA_ID"       Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdAssignedTo"   Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdActEndDate"   Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdProjectName"  Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdChargeNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdDatasheetURL" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdComments"     Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdMEPartNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdTopStatus"    Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdSymStatus"    Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdSymChecked"   Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdFtpStatus"    Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdFtpChecked"   Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UdParamStatus"  Type="String" />
     </UpdateParameters>

   </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: please show your `OnRowEditing` code

Comment: At present, OnRowEditing is just a stub with no content.  At one point I tried re-binding the Gridview there, but the link to data is lost after this event is finished, so I removed that code.

Comment: Ok, solved.  Or at least, works as I want it to.  I do the initial search on the first page load, and save the SQL Select command in a hidden field.  I also save it on later, custom searches.  In the PageLoad routine, if the load *is* a postback, I re-issue the most recent Select command, and the Gridview comes up in Edit mode with the proper data, visible and everything.  WHY I had to do all this is still a bit puzzling - I've never had to do this re-selection before.  Still, thanks to everyone for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to re-bind the grid at all points that I can think of (either re-setting the DataSourceID string, or that and issuing a DataBind() call) at PageLoad, and at various event handlers.

I suspect this is your problem.  Based on your description it doesn't sound like you would ever need to explicitly re-bind the grid, and when doing so you should expect the state of the grid to get reset.  I suggest removing all calls to DataBind() or resetting the DataSourceID.

Comment: No joy.  The DataSourceID is set once, during the initial page load, and the problem still occurs.

Comment: In fact, I declared DataSourceID="EDASource" in the gridview itself, and removed any programatic reference to that property from the code-behind, and the problem still happens.  It loses it's data when entering any Command button state.

Comment: @Chris How are the SelectParameter values set?

Comment: In the routine (button click event) that performs the search.

Comment: Through debugging you should make sure those parameter values are being preserved across postbacks.  Changes in parameter values will cause the Grid to automatically re-bind.

Answer (score 0):

Code behind of the page should definitely help to analyze the problem.

Most common reason is data-binding in even postback.
So make sure your databinding in pageload is like this:

```
if(!Page.PostBack){
//Your Grid Databinding
}
```

Comment: I've tried having the initial (and only) databind happen inside a  if(!IsPostback) block, and having the DataSourceID be set declaritively and never touched by code-behind.  The behavior is identical in either case - everything works in normal searching, but acts like there's no rows found when any Command button (Edit, Update, or Cancel) is clicked.

Comment: Can you do a sql trace / use sqlProfiler to see what exactly is called?

Comment: Sadly, I don't have profiler access. I do catch the OnSelected event at the DataSource, and a breakpoint on it shows that the data source isn't being selected when Edit clicks.  It's something in the Gridview - I hit Edit, and after RowEditing, it enters Edit mode.  It goes through it's rows, firing a RowDataBound event when it tries to re-draw the first row.  Then, it finds no other rows and displays EmptyDataText.  When I re-select the search, it fires RowDataBound events for each row, and displays the Gridview in edit mode. The search is SQL commands, not a stored procedure.

Comment: 1: If possible I would go to DBA and ask to run a trace on that particular storedprocedure. 2) I would start with narrowing down the Grid with first one or two columns. My one guess it could be some Binding issue with DDL in editmode could be causing that. Can you try changing it to a readonly. Again that's just a guess.

Comment: Ummm.... there is no stored procedure. I was probably unclear in the last line of the previous comment. I can try removing some columns and playing with making some ReadOnly, but I really don't think it's related to those sorts of details.

Comment: Oh I see that you don't have a DataSourceID set for your GV. Where and how is your EDASource linked to your GV? Can we see the DataBinding code-behind?

Comment: Initially, the DataSourceID was set at the initial search on PageLoad. In response to several suggestions here, I've moved that into the Gridview declaration - there is a DataSourceID="EDASource" term in there now. And that's the only mention - codebehind does not do anything with it right now.  Searches still work, so I have to believe that the DataSourceID stays set throughout the page session.